# Swift Mutation inside switch with associated values

Tags: ios, swift, struct, mutating-function

I have these structs I want to mutate:

```
public struct CheckoutViewModel {
    var sections: [Section]
    var total: String

    public struct Section {
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var kind: Kind
        var expandState: ExpandState

        enum Kind {
            case products([ProductOrderViewModel])
            case shippingMode(SelectableArray<ShippingMode>)
            case shippingTarget(SelectableArray<ShippingKind>)
            case billingAddress(SelectableArray<Address>)
            case payment(SelectableArray<PaymentProvider>)
            case promoCode(String?)
            case legalAdvice(userAccepted: Bool)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectableArray<T> {
    var selectedIndex: Int?
    let options: [T]

    init(options: [T]) {
        self.options = options
        self.selectedIndex = nil
    }

    mutating func select(atIndex: Int) throws -> T {
        guard atIndex < options.count else {
            throw SelectableArrayError.outOfBoundsIndex
        }
        selectedIndex = atIndex
        return options[atIndex]
    }

    var selectedElement: T? {
        guard let selectedIndex = selectedIndex else { return nil }
        return options[selectedIndex]
    }
}
```

I want to use this mutating func select() method inside SelectableArray, I am calling it from a chain of mutating functions (because Sections is nested inside a struct)

```
extension CheckoutViewModel {  
    mutating func select(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        sections[indexPath.section].select(atIndex: indexPath.row)
    }
}

extension CheckoutViewModel.Section {
    mutating func select(atIndex idx: Int) {
        switch kind {
            case .shippingMode(var modes):
                do { _ = try modes.select(atIndex: idx) } catch { return }
            default:
                return nil
        }
        dump(self) // Here self hasn't changed
    }
}
```

The problem is that the CheckoutViewModel struct is never mutated. I am guessing that switch is not a mutating function, so `var modes` inside that switch is non mutable and then it does not matter if the following functions mutate anything. The workaround I managed to do is this:

```
mutating func select(atIndex idx: Int) {
    switch kind {
    case .shippingMode(var modes):
        do {
            _ = try modes.select(atIndex: idx)
            self.kind = .shippingMode(modes)
        } catch { return }
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Do you have any oher solution to this problem? Is there any sort of `mutating switch` function that I can use?

Comment: The switch is irrelevant. The issue here is that a `mutating` function only mutates the instance it was called on. Because structs are value types, copies are made upon assignment (including when being passed into functions). As a result, you're only mutating copies, and not updating the larger structure with the new mutated child.

Comment: I don't agree. Considering only the last select function I proposed, if I comment out the line `self.kind = .shippingMode(modes)` after the switch statement, self is not changed at all. If instead I assign self.kind, then inside self.kind there is the `SelectableArray` struct, containing a selectedIndex equal to `idx`

Comment: In your question, you have a solution to your own problem. Clearly, the `var modes` is mutable, since you're calling a mutating function on it. If it weren't, you would have a compiler error. The issue here is that `var modes` creates a copy of the associated value of `modes`, which you then successfully mutate. The issue is that you've mutated a copy that's completely separate from the rest of your structure. The solution to this is assign this mutated copy back into `kind`, just as you did. Again, this has nothing to do with `switch`, but the way value types work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120):

> A `switch` case can bind the value or values it matches to temporary
>   constants or variables, for use in the body of the case. This behavior
>   is known as value binding, because the values are bound to temporary
>   constants or variables within the case’s body.

Changes to such a temporary variable (e.g. the `modes` variable) do not affect the contents of the enum that is being switched on (e.g. `kind`).

For your first approach to work you would indeed need a different sort of switch statement that creates a reference to the enum's associated value, allowing you to modify that value in place. Such a statement doesn't exist in Swift 3.0.1.